# Instruccion DriveApp.searchfiles

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive

En Google App Script estoy haciendo un algoritmo que consiste en buscar un archivo en el google drive y grabar su dirección URL para futuro uso. Para buscar el archivo uso la siguiente secuencia de instrucciones:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains variable');
while (files.hasNext())
{
  var file = files.next();   
  var dato = file.getUrl();
}
```

siendo variable una variable que tiene adentro una cadena de texto que es el nombre del archivo que quiero buscar.

Esta instrucción no me funciona. Sin embargo, si pongo en el lugar donde está la variable el nombre que quiero buscar entre comillas dobles, todo funciona correctamente. Pero el nombre que quiero buscar no lo puedo tipear ya que lo quiero hacer en forma automática sin necesidad de escribir el nombre. Y ese nombre está dentro del valor de la variable. Además, dentro de variable está el nombre entre comillas dobles ya que lo reconoce como cadena de texto.

He probado escribir variable sin comillas como esta en el ejemplo, entre comillas dobles ("variable"), entre comillas simples ('variable') y ninguno de los 3 funciona.

¿Me podran decir cómo puedo hacer que la instrucción tome variable y funcione?

Comment: Hola Marcelo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general, y que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus publicaciones.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + variable + '"');
```

poniendo la variable entre comillas dobles.

Answer (score 0):

El manejo de cadenas de texto en Google Apps Script es el mismo que se realiza en JavaScript. Usa el operador `+` para concatenar dos cadenas. En el caso de un literal y una variable sería de la siguiente forma

```javascript
'esta es una cadena literal ' + variable
```

Por otro lado, como se menciona en [la respuesta de Joan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/176525/65), el argumento de `searchFiles` requiere que el valor que se va a buscar en el título (`title`) se indique entre comillas dobles `"`

Aplicando lo anterior al código del OP

```js
var variable = 'nombre';
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + variable + '"');
while (files.hasNext())
{
  var file = files.next();   
  var dato = file.getUrl();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

***Si entendí lo que quieres hacer, es agregar una variable en donde debería ir texto?***

*Por ejemplo en el método `setAttribute`:*

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
console.log("Función realiza, DOM CARGADO..")
var divEjemplo = document.getElementById("ejemplo");
var atributo = "2px solid purple";
divEjemplo.setAttribute("style",'border: '+atributo+''); /* Aquí va la magia */
});
```

```css
#ejemplo { width:300px;height:300px;background-color:lightpink;border-radius:150px; }
```

```html
<div id="ejemplo"></div>
```

*Agregas comillas IGUALES y el operador `+` **ANTES Y DESPUÉS** DE LA VARIABLE, `'texto: '+variable+'';`*

Comment: Hola Eduardo. Gracias por tu respuesta pero no me funciona. hice lo siguiente : DirveApp.searchFiles( 'title contains '+valor+'') y la ejecucion se traba en el while de la siguiente instrucción. Luego probe ( 'title contains "+valor+"') es decir con doble comillas y se ejecuta pero el valor que aparece es indefinido. Tenes idea de que puede ser.

Comment: Podrias decirme donde se encuentra tu código? para verlo completo y así ayudarte de mejor manera

Comment: En el código del lado del servidor de Google Apps Script no es posible usar el DOM ni los métodos de este. En cuanto a lo de agregar comillas, no es necesario agregar una cadena vacía.