# Por que no me funciona el DriveApp.searchFiles cuando le paso la query en una variable pero si que funciona si le paso un string?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Tengo un problema que no soy capaz de resolver desde hace días.

Tengo un código que se encarga de generarme una query para llamar al `searchFiles` de Google Apps Script.

Me da problemas en la ejecución:

> Exception: Argumento no válido: q at GetFilesInFolder

Se que este problema es por que la query no esta bien ( aunque no sepa ver donde esta el problema )

Hago un log para capturar lo que llamo y lo pongo directamente en la llamada al `searchFiles`, funciona.

```
Logger.log(query);                              // Aqui capturo la query que uso
var files = folder.searchFiles(query);  // Esta llamada da problemas

var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate > "2020-10-10" and mimeType = "application/pdf" and title contains "this" and not title contains "hgdk" ');  // Aqui uso la llamada tal como la logeo...funciona.
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que debes tener presente es que cuando se pasa una variable como argumento a `Logger.log` este la va a convertir a una cadena de texto, posiblemente usando `toString()`, `valueOf()` del objeto global Object o le que corresponda en la cadena de prototipos. Si a la variable se le va a asignar un objeto o bien para "pecar" de precabido, en lugar de

```
Logger.log(query);
```

mejor usa

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(query, null, ''));
```

Habría que ver que se ha asignado a `query`.

En cuanto a la parámetro de `searchFiles`, puedes construir tu string usando `'` pero habrá que usar `"` como delimitador de los valores con los que se compararan las palabras claves como `modifiedDate` y `mimeType`. Si has usado `"` como delimitador de tu cadena de texto, al usarlo como delimitador de los valores deberás escaparlo como has mencionado en tu respuesta.

---

Ejemplo usando una variable en lugar de un literal como parámetro de `searchFiles`

```
function myFunction() {
  var query = 'title contains "prueba"';
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(query);
  var count = 0;
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    count++
  }
  console.log(count);
}
```

Relacionado

- [Instruccion DriveApp.searchfiles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/101855/65)

Comment: Lo que dices es correcto Rubén. El problema es que si llamas al searchFiles directamente le puedes poner el simbolo ', pero si lo pones dentro de una variable y usas esa variable en el searchFiles no funciona. Tal vez haciendo el stringify me habría funcionado. Debería probarlo. Gracias!

Comment: @PakoLordPakus ¿Cómo estás creando la cadena de texto y cómo la asignas a la variable?

Comment: Siguiendo la documentación. Simbolo ' para contener el total de la query y simbolo " para contener los "parametros" de mimeType , titulos y similares. La gracia del código es que en base a lo que hay en un spreadsheet hace la query de una manera u otra. El problema de hacerlo así es que no funcionaba :). Cuando pase a " para la query general y \" para contener los parametros, todo perfecto.

Comment: @PakoLordPakus Te sugiero crear un [mcve]. Nota: He puesto un  ejemplo que demuestra que pasar una variable como argumento de `searchFiles` funciona

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución , al menos a mi problema.

Todo parece ser que era un problema con `'` y `"`.

Al pasarlo todo a `"` y `\"` todo ha funcionado a la primera.

Importante, no ponerle ni `"` ni `'` al inicio y al final de la query.

Entiendo que cuando montamos la query dentro de un string no se comporta igual cuando lo pasamos como parametro a `searchFiles` que cuando hacemos un `Logger.log`.

Todo es un problema de formateo de los strings.